# Error spotting inspiration required: certificate_unknown and SSLHandshakeException on Payara

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, payara

I'm banging my head where the error is, so I need a little error tracking inspiration.

I try to call a webservice on a remote server from a Java web app that is running on my dockerized Payara 4.1. Docker image is using Alpine Linux with Java 8.

When I attempt to call the service I get a

**Certificate_unknown thrown by an SSLHandshakeException**

I know this means that the **chain of trust is not complete** and a certificate (root/intermediary) is missing.

When I check the ssl connection via openssl with

```
openssl s_client -connect server:port -CAfile certificate_exported_from_remote_server.per
```

its working fine ('Verify return code: 0 (ok)'.

```
openssl s_client -connect server:port -CAfile path_to_payara/config/cacerts.jks
```

does not work (`Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`), but I haven't found out if I can use openssl with a keystore.

Anyway, I've imported all certificates (root/intermediary) I could download from the remote webservice' server and installed them via keytool

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias cert -file downloadedcertificate.cer -keystore payara_path/config/cacerts.jks --storepass pwd -noprompt
```

When I list using `keytool -list -keystore` it shows that the certificates were imported.

In the `domain.xml` the jvm-option `-Djavax.ssl.trustStore` points to the cacerts.jks.

I thought that this is the correct way, but I still get this error and I'm too blind to see what I did wrong.

**Thus, I'm asking for some inspiration to spot the error.**

Comment: (1) OpenSSL doesn't read JKS format, and `openssl s_client` has option `-connect` with a hyphen not `connect` (2) cert not in Java truststore usually produces exception related to PKIX path building (3) I bet if you look _carefully_ at your exception it is more like `received alert certificate_unknown` -- if so the problem is not your client's trust of the server cert's, but the server's trust of your client's cert; look at that, or add that to your Q.

Comment: Yes, the payara log shows `RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, certificate_unknown'. So you're saying the auto generated certificate from my Payara is not accepted by the server I'm querying. This means I should create a certificate that is accepted by the webservice server?

Comment: You need to use a cert accepted by the server, yes -- or possibly no cert at all if the server allows that (some do, some don't, it might depend on what request(s) you send). I don't know what your 'auto generated' consists of but normally you need to obtain the cert from a CA that is trusted by the server; this _may_ be limited to the wellknown CAs like GoDaddy DigiCert etc but it depends on the server. CA-issued certs almost always need a chain cert (sometimes more than one); be sure that's in your keystore entry (if you use `keytool` it normally does this automatically).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a locally generated certificate, you need to import it to the remote server. What you did is you imported remote certificate to a local trust store which could possibly work if OpenSSL picked that exact one from the trust store, but I assume there are more certificates in the loca ltrust store and it picks a certificate that's not on the remote server's trust store.

The rule is simple: the certificate used by the client has to be present in the remote server's truststore